# pandas search a value in a dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I have following dataframe and i want to search apple in column fruits and display all the rows if apple is found.

```
Before : 
   number fruits     purchase
    0       apple     yes
            mango
            banana
    1       apple     no
            cheery      
    2       mango     yes
            banana
    3       apple     yes
            orange
    4       grapes    no
            pear

After:            
    number fruits     purchase
    0       apple     yes
            mango
            banana
    1       apple     no
            cheery      
    3       apple     yes
            orange
```

Comment: fruits column type is list or string ?

Comment: fruits column type is object

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `filter` to filter groups that contain 'apple':

```
df['number'] = df['number'].ffill()

df.groupby('number').filter(lambda x: (x['fruits'] == 'apple').any())

df_out.assign(number = df_out['number'].mask(df.number.duplicated()))\
  .replace(np.nan,'')
```

Output:

```
  number  fruits purchase
0      0   apple      yes
1          mango         
2         banana         
3      1   apple       no
4         cheery         
7      3   apple      yes
8         orange
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `'number'` as the index, so I'm going to assume that.

Get the numbers where `'apple'` is present, and slice into those:

```
idx = df.index[df.fruits == 'apple']
df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: i am not using number as the index.